# Pollard Rho factorization method

Tags: algorithm

Pollard Rho factorization method uses a function generator f(x) = x^2-a(mod n) or f(x) = x^2+a(mod n) , is the choice of this function (parabolic) has got any significance or we may use any function (cubic , polynomial or even linear) as we have to identify or find the numbers belonging to same congruence class modulo n to find the non trivial divisor ?

Comment: Doesn't appear to matter.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard's_rho_algorithm#Core_ideas states that the generator function only needs to be pseudorandom.

Comment: Then why we don't just use a linear function ..... I mean cubic , polynomial may increase calculations and may lead to overflow but why we don't just use a linear function ?

Comment: It should be pseudorandom, and the modulus of the square of a large number will appear to jump around quickly, but a linear function might appear to be less random.  If you're checking numbers that are intervals of 1 apart using a 'linear pseudorandom generator' then after checking a bunch of numbers you will say with high confidence that these numbers are coprime, even though they have large common factors.  In short, when the algorithm calls for random numbers don't use a linear progression or you may get correctness issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Knuth Vol II (The Art Of Computer Programming - Seminumerical Algorithms) section 4.5.4 Knuth says

> Furthermore if f(y) mod p behaves as a random mapping from the set {0,
>   1, ... p-1} into itself, exercise 3.1-12 shows that the average value
>   of the least such m will be of order sqrt(p)... From the theory in
>   Chapter 3, we know that a linear polynomial f(x) = ax + c will not be
>   sufficiently random for our purpose. The next simplest case is
>   quadratic, say f(x) = x^2 + 1. We don't *know* that this function is
>   sufficiently random, but our lack of knowledge tends to support the
>   hypothesis of randomness, and empirical tests show that this f does
>   work essentially as predicted

The probability theory that says that f(x) has a cycle of length about sqrt(p) assumes in particular that there can be two values y and z such that f(y) = f(z) - since f is chosen at random. The rho in Pollard Rho contains such a junction, with the cycle containing multiple lines leading on to it. For a linear function f(x) = ax + b then for gcd(a, p) = 1 mod p (which is likely since p is prime) f(y) = f(z) means that y = z mod p, so there are no such junctions.

If you look at http://www.agner.org/random/theory/chaosran.pdf you will see that the expected cycle length of a random function is about the sqrt of the state size, but the expected cycle length of a random bijection is about the state size. If you think of generating the random function only as you evaluate it you can see that if the function is entirely random then every value seen so far is available to be chosen again at random to find a cycle, so the odds of closing the cycle increase with the cycle length, but if the function has to be invertible the only way to close the cycle is to generate the starting point, which is much less likely.